# implementing reverse proxy with nginx and docker containers with different ports

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-container

i have three docker containers on different ports and would like to implement reverse proxy with nginx to each of the containers so that i can navigate to each of the containers by passing a keyword instead of ports. Like Instead of `http://localhost:3000` i want to pass like `http://localhost/app1`

I created the nginx image with below dockerfile.

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY index.html usr/share/nginx/html
```

and my nginx conf file looks like this:

```
worker_processes 1;


events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream app1 {
        server localhost:3000;
    }

    upstream app2 {
        server localhost:3001;
    }

    server {
        listen 3000;

        location /app1 {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 3001;

        location /app2 {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:3001;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

but after creating the nginx container from the image. I see the container created. but when i tried to access with localhost it timed out so nginx is not running or did i miss something. I cannot load the container with localhost/app1 or app2 or even localhost is not working. help needed. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are exposing the ports 80 and 443 when you start the container but I don't see you listening to those ports in the nginx configuration.

Please try replacing `listen 3000` by `listen 80` and then try accessing `localhost/app1`

I can also see that you are using `--link` when you start your docker container. So I think you should use `app1` and `app2` instead of `localhost`. Please let me know if there is something that I missed so it isn't the case. You must also make sure that your applications are accessible on these ports (3000 and 3001).

Also your 2 locations should be in the same server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass         http://app1:3000;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass         http://app2:3001;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aussourd thanks for your answer. i did change it to listen to port 80 but now i get 500 error

Comment: @Jes it usually means that your app is crashing. You should check your app logs